# Recreate 3 column facebook style parcial scrolling then fixed position CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i want to know how to achieve the facebook effect for its 3 columns, if you check you can scroll the page as a usual page until the right column stop scrolling, and the center scrolling keep doing it, How is that 3er column on the right working, why you can scroll it until its fixed on the page.. i guess this is javascript. right?

For the rest of elements i think header is fixed , thats clear, but that 3er column is killing me cause i need to recreate a timeline (with other design) but the same idea of 3 columns..

Any ideas? All the examples i can found, set a fixed position for Rigth column , but in facebook as i said you can scroll until 3rd column became fixed, well i think i dont know, thats why i ask.

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at the Bootstrap Affix component. It almost does what you want. With a little bit of extra CSS you should be able to get it working. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#affix

Comment: Nice!, i do not understand quite well how does it work ,its there any other link with examples using affix onscroll, i will google anyway thanks

Comment: I just found what i need thanks to you! wahoo http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't too difficult once you break it down into steps...

Firstly, you need to set up your page template in `html`:

```
<div class="head">
    <!-- HEAD CONTENT GOES HERE -->
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- LEFT BAR CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div
    ><div class="right">
        <!-- RIGHT BAR CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to style it however you want it to look with `css`:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.head{
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#3B5998;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:1000;
}
.main{
    padding:30px 10px 5px;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:auto;
}
.left{
    vertical-align:top;
    width:80%;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:#eee;
}
.right{
    vertical-align:top;
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Then you need to understand what is needed to make this work...

To start with you need to know:

1. The height of the viewing window
2. The height to which the window is scrolled
3. The height of the right bar

The idea is to have the right bar (`.right`) scroll with the rest of the page (as it does with the plain `html` and `css` above) until the end of `.right` is reached.

Mathematically this will happen when:

```
window_height + scroll_height == right_bar_height
```

Now that you know when you need to *start stopping* `.right` from scrolling you can plug it into an if statement and add the custom `css` to fix the right bar in place.

To fix `.right` in the correct place you need to know:

1. The height of the window
2. The height of `.right`
3. The width of `.right`
4. The left offset of `.right` in the viewing window

You then apply `css` attributes with `js` to fix `.right` in the correct place. That is `position`, `top`, `left`, and `width`.

1. You set `position: fixed` so that `.right` is taken out of the flow of the page.
2. You set `left` to the sum of `.left` offset and `.left` width
3. You set `top` to `window_height - right_bar_height` but only if `.right` is taller than the window
4. You set `width` to the desired width. In this case 20% of `.main`

You then need to apply the above calculations every time the page `scrolls` or `resizes` so it's best to have it as a function which you can call in either event.

```
function rightBarControl(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
    var rightBarWidth = $('.main').width()*.2 //20% of .main width
    var rightBarHeight = $('.right').outerHeight();
    var rightBarOffset = $('.left').offset().left + $('.left').outerWidth();
    var rightBarTop = 30; //30 because .head is 30px high
    if(windowHeight - 30 < rightBarHeight){ //Again including 30 because of .head
        rightBarTop = windowHeight - rightBarHeight;
    }
    if((windowHeight + scrollHeight) >= rightBarHeight){
        $('.right').css({
            position:'fixed',
            left: rightBarOffset,
            top: rightBarTop,
            width: rightBarWidth
        })
    }
    else{
         $('.right').css({
            position: 'static',
            left: '',
            top: '',
            width: '20%'
        })
    }
}
$(window).scroll(rightBarControl); //Run control on window scroll
$(window).resize(rightBarControl); //Run control on window resize
```

Note this use `jquery` so you need to include it before the above script, something like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```